# A state of a C* algebra which preserves square of a self adjoint element

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $ϕ$ be a state on a $C∗$-algebra $ A$. Suppose that for some selfadjoint element $a ∈ A$ one has $ ϕ(a^{2}) = ϕ(a)^2$. Show that this implies that $ϕ(ab) = ϕ(ba) = ϕ(a)ϕ(b)$ for any $ b ∈ A$.

My step : easy to check that it is enough to prove the theorem in case $b=b^*$. When we need to prove that $ϕ(ab) = \overline{ϕ(ab)}$.

But what's next? Could you take me some small hint?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm wrong, but from what you wrote it looks like you are missing the point. The hard thing is to prove that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$. And the other equality requires a similar proof "on the other side" (and one of the equalities does not imply the other).

The fact you want to prove holds more generally for unital completely positive maps: if $\Phi$ is ucp and $\Phi(a^*a)=\Phi(a)^*\Phi(a)$, then $a$ is in the *multiplicative domain* of $\Phi$, which means precisely that $\Phi(ab)=\Phi(a)\phi(b)$ for any $b$.

In your case, since $\phi$ is a state things are a bit simpler, and what you want is a simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz. Namely, apply Cauchy-Schwarz to
$$
|\phi((a-\phi(a))b)|. 
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution is wonderful! And with a simple change may be used for a C* algebra without unit

Comment: The unit is not a big deal because states extend trivially to the unitization, so for the sake of the argument you may assume that  $A $ is unital.